# Conflict with style and sprintf

Tags: css, printf

I have a define statement that uses inline styling. When I try to call it with a sprintf function, it fails with Too Few Arguments.  The define looks like this

```
define('TEXT_HEADING', ' 
<div style="float:left; width:60%; height:44px">
<p>Title Goes here</p>
<p>Show results: %s</p>
');
```

The call like this:

```
echo sprintf(TEXT_HEADING, 14);
```

If i remove the style statement, it works as expected. The original code is quite large and has many inline styles. Moving those to classes may allow it to work but isn't an option. is there a way to get this to work as shown?

Comment: this seems like a php question, you should tag id accordingly.

Comment: that being said, you are using a string specifier %s, and passing an int as a argument, try quoting your argument sprintf(TEXT_HEADING, "14").

Comment: I apologize for not marking the question correctly. You are correct, it is php related. I tried adding quotes but it fails the same.

Comment: You need to escape your literal percent sign, try replacing width:60% with width:60%%

Comment: Excellent - that worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to post this as an answer, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your literal percent sign, try replacing

```
width:60%
```

with

```
 width:60%%
```